# Block URLs that begin and end in common prefixes and suffixes using robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, disallow

I have the urls like:
`/category1/type-name-more`
And I need to disallow all urls of this type.

`Disallow: /*-more$` is not OK as it may block all the urls ending in `-more`. So is the variant
`Disallow: /category1/ */-more$`
correct in such case? To disallow all the urls in the `/category1/` section and ending in `-more`?

More info: `-name-` is always changing in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> So is the variant `Disallow: /category1/ */-more$` correct

Almost, but you seem to have introduced an erroneous *space* and slash that is not present in your example, so this won't block the crawling of these URLs.

> To disallow all the urls in the `/category1/` section and ending in `-more`?

The `*` "designates 0 or more instances of any valid character", so you need the following instead:

```
Disallow: /category1/*-more$
```

Reference:

- https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt